# Place boxes with text on image, using bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I would like to add some boxes hovering an image.

I have tried many ways but I'm unable to achieve the desired result ([an image of the desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Trt3n.jpg)).

This is my HTML code:

```
<img src="F:\Theme Development\New folder\6592.jpg" style="position:absolute;" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
<div class="row">
  <div class="text-right col-md-3 offset-md-3 left-block">
    <h4>Easiest way to fint the job</h4>
    <p>It is long established fact that a reader will be distracted by readable content of a page when looking at its layout</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"> Find Job</a>
  </div>
  <div class="text-right right-block col-md-3 col-md-3">
    <h4>Easiest way to fint the job</h4>
    <p>It is long established fact that a reader will be distracted by readable content of a page when looking at its layout</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Post Resume</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS code:

```
.right-block {
   position: absolute;
   width: 18rem;
   background-color: #00cc99;
   opacity: 0.5;
   color: white;
   padding: 20px 20px
 }

 .left-block {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50rem;
    background-color: #00cc99;
    opacity: 0.5;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px 20px
  }
```

Comment: could you make your question more clear

Comment: Yes but if you see the image i have uploaded in the last line of my post then my question will be clear to you. I want same replica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. This background image is only demo purpose.

```css
.right-block {     
   background-color: #00cc99;
   opacity: 0.5;
   color: white;
   padding: 20px 20px
}
.comm-block{
  display:inline-block;
  width:30%;
}
.left-block {  
  background-color: #00cc99;
  opacity: 0.5;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px 20px
}
.img-wrap{
  position:relative;
}
.img-block {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="img-wrap">
  <div class="img">
  <img src="http://www.abstract-living.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/meeting-strangers.jpg"  class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
  </div>
  <div class="img-block text-center">
  
  <div class="comm-block">
  <div class="left-block">
    <h4>Easiest way to fint the job</h4>
    <p>It is long established fact that a reader will be distracted by readable content of a page when looking at its layout</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"> Find Job</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="comm-block">
    <div class="right-block">
    <h4>Easiest way to fint the job</h4>
    <p>It is long established fact that a reader will be distracted by readable content of a page when looking at its layout</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Post Resume</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need these two blocks in bottom center of the background image.if you see the image i have uploaded in my question.

Comment: yes two blocks are bottom center. did you check it..? please check it.

Comment: i check it if i use .img-fluid class with image then two boxes are in the center of the image not in the bottom center.

Comment: thanks dear this one working. Although i have made little changes but this one is now perfect as i want it to be. Again thanks for your time and support.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution using bootstrap v4,

Basically I used default bootstrap flexbox classes to push the green boxes at the end using `align-items-end` and center then using `justify-content-center`

Its not a proper solution, but it will give you a starting point.

Open the snippet in full page view,

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.left-block,.right-block{
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="parent d-flex align-items-end justify-content-center">
      <img src="HTTPS://PLACEHOLD.IT/1500x500" class="" alt="Responsive image">.
      <div class="text-right col-md-4 left-block">
        <h4>Easiest way to fint the job</h4>
        <p>It is long established fact that a reader will be distracted by readable content of a page when looking at its layout</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"> Find Job</a>
      </div>
      <div class="text-left col-md-4 right-block">
        <h4>Easiest way to fint the job</h4>
        <p>It is long established fact that a reader will be distracted by readable content of a page when looking at its layout</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"> Find Job</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please if you could add the class img-fluid to the image then the result become totally different

Comment: @AsadMarwat, img-fluid, gives auto height to image, thats y it breaks

Comment: @AsadMarwat, if u want, u can set it as background-image to div

Answer (score 0):

Check this according to your example image I think it helps you out

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 banner-img">
  <div class="row text-block">
    <div class="text-right col-md-3 offset-md-3 ">
      <div class="left-block">
        <h4>Easiest way to fint the job</h4>
        <p>It is long established fact that a reader will be distracted by readable content of a page when looking at its layout</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"> Find Job</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-right col-md-3 col-md-3">
      <div class="right-block">
        <h4>Easiest way to fint the job</h4>
        <p>It is long established fact that a reader will be distracted by readable content of a page when looking at its layout</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Post Resume</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x450" style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:450px;" class="banner-main" alt="Responsive image">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.banner-img {
  position:relative;
  height:450px;
  overflow:hidden;
}.banner-main {
  top:0;
  z-index:-1;
}
.text-block {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
.right-block {

   background-color: #00cc99;
   opacity: 0.5;
   color: white;
   padding: 20px 20px;
   z-index: 9;
  margin-top:215px;
 }

 .left-block {
    background-color: #00cc99;
    opacity: 0.5;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    z-index: 9;
    margin-top:215px;
  }
```

example: [demo link](https://codepen.io/zaheerahamd/pen/mjzLzg/)